# Finding the Big-O notation with logarithms involved.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, logarithms, computer-science

I am trying to understand algorithms and especially the Big-O notation and I came across this question that included logs:

The question wants me to prove that the Big-O notations for $\log_3 x$ is $\log_2 x$. 
I know how to solve the ones with no logs, but I am very confused on how to approach the ones with logs. Thank you so much in advance!

Do I start by breaking it down?

$\log_3 x$ is $O(\log_2 x)$, where $3$ and $2$ are the log bases.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the change of base formula for logs
\begin{align}
\frac{\log_2 y}{\log_2 3} = \log_3 y.  
\end{align}

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean :( @JackyChong

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}$ is a constant ...